# Миграция с windows на ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, express, sequelize.js

разрабатываю приложения словаря для себя. приложение прекрасно работает на windows 10. суть приложения клиент - reactjs (с ним проблем нет), работает в windows 10 и в  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. с server - проблемы. сервер на express с подключение к базе данных MySQl через sequelize. база данных создана, служба MySql активна , пароль для рута и для базы данных одинаковый. но при запуске сервера на Ubuntu у меня ошибка. в целом всё приложение работает в windows 10 без ошибок и так как я того хочу.
`

```
   1] ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
    [1]     at ConnectionManager.connect (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:102:17)
    [1]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    [1]     at async ConnectionManager._connect (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:222:24)
    [1]     at async /root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32
    [1]     at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-

    manager.js:197:7)
        [1]     at async /root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:305:26
        [1]     at async Sequelize.authenticate (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:457:5)
        [1]     at async start (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/dist/index.js:23:9) {
        [1]   parent: Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
        [1]       at Packet.asError (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
        [1]       at ClientHandshake.execute (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
        [1]       at Connection.handlePacket (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:478:34)
        [1]       at PacketParser.onPacket (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:97:12)
        [1]       at PacketParser.executeStart (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
        [1]       at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:104:25)
        [1]       at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
        [1]       at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:545:12)
        [1]       at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:495:3)
        [1]       at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:375:5) {
        [1]     code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_NO_PASSWORD_ERROR',
        [1]     errno: 1698,
        [1]     sqlState: '28000',
        [1]     sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'",
        [1]     sql: undefined
        [1]   },
        [1]   original: Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
        [1]       at Packet.asError (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
        [1]       at ClientHandshake.execute (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
        [1]       at Connection.handlePacket (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:478:34)
        [1]       at PacketParser.onPacket (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:97:12)
        [1]       at PacketParser.executeStart (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
        [1]       at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/dictionary/server_for_dictionary/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:104:25)
        [1]       at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
        [1]       at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:545:12)
        [1]       at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:495:3)
        [1]       at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:375:5) {
        [1]     code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_NO_PASSWORD_ERROR',
        [1]     errno: 1698,
        [1]     sqlState: '28000',
        [1]     sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'",
        [1]     sql: undefined
        [1]   }
        [1] }
```

пример кода подключения к дб:

```
const sequelize: Sequelize = new Sequelize('dictionary', 'root', '11111', {
        dialect: "mysql",
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
    });
```

собственно сам сервер

```
const start = async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        await sequelize.sync();
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};

start();
```

Собственно сам вопрос ,что мне делать  и куда бежать? как исправить ошибку подключения к базе данных?
P.s. извините , что дал много ненужной информации.

Comment: Ну как бы логичный вопрос — логин и пароль от базы правильные ли вообще? И что вы предприняли для того, чтобы они были правильные?

Comment: спасибо вам большое) показали в каком направлении думать. после команд (покажу ниже)  всё заработало.   mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '11111';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> exit;